# How do i add multiple Images from my Firebase Database to my ArrayList

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-storage

```
public class getFirebase extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference dbRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_firebase);

        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("theimage");

        final List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<>();

        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        })

    }
}
```

I have uploaded the images to my firebase Storage and then copied the image link to my database child "theimage". Refer uploaded Image.

put images storage link inside "theimage" node
[image]

What do you think is the best way to get all the images from my firebase Database to my ArrayList?

Comment: Please add a more detailed screenshot of your database.

Comment: a more detailed screenshot uploaded

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through your `DataSnapshot` to get all the images into `ArrayList`. Beside this your `ArrayList` should be `String` type. Check below:

```
final List<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            images.add(childSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

If you also want to get the key like *apple*, *samsung* then you have to use  `Map` instead of `ArrayList`. check below:

```
final Map<String, String> images = new HashMap<>();

dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            images.put(childSnapshot.getKey(), childSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting "Incompatible Types"  error:  Required - com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot . Found - com.firebase.client.Datasnapshot

Comment: inside public void onDataChange

Comment: I mentioned in my post your `ArrayList` should be `String` instead of `Integer`. `copy-paste` my solution and check

Comment: I am posting a new question explaining the complete issue.

Comment: That means it is not solve your problem, right? Or you face another problem?

Comment: Yes. what I am trying to achieve is get images into my ArrayList and then pass the ArrayList as a parameter in my Custom adapter that I am using to display both image and name from firebase data and using that adapter for grid view.

Comment: That is new problem. What about your current problem that you mentioned in the titled of this question. Is that solve? Do your get data inside `onDataChange`? For image and name, I add 2nd options

Comment: No, I did not get data

Comment: Then there is some other problems. According your data my solution should work. Bty thanks

Comment: `com.firebase.client.Datasnapshot` is an incredibly old version of the Firebase SDK (before May 2016). It looks like you have multiple SDKs for the Firebase Database in your app. Stick to just one version of the SDK, preferably the latest as documented on firebase.google.com.